# Why do my Bootstrap grid divs overlap when i put columns in a row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

Let's say I have a simple layout consisting of two rows using the Bootstrap grid system.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="well">
                "Goodmorning!"
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="well">
                "Goodnight!"
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

From this I get the expected appearance: https://i.stack.imgur.com/odKpY.jpg

However, as soon as I decide to put some columns in the first row, the rows then overlap a bit.

HTML:

```
        <div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="well">
                    "Goodmorning!"
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="well">
                    "Goodmorning!"
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="well">
                "Goodnight!"
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I expect to see a lay out that has two column in the first row, and no columns in the second row. However, the output is overlapping: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1GDa.jpg

I realize I'm doing something wrong, but intuitively, this seems like it should work fine. Any ideas?

Comment: row-fluid isn't a part of Bootstrap v3, use row and see if that helps.

Comment: @vanburen That was exactly it. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome and glad I could help.